# Linq to Objects DateTime Except ignore time

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 2 `List<DateTime>` and want to return the subset of the first list that isn't in the second list but ignore the time.

Is it possible to do this using the Except extension method?

```
var missingDates = dateList1.Except(dateList2);
```

Would I need to set the time in both lists to `00:00:00` or is there some way I can use the `.Date` property to compare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var missingDates = dateList1.Select(x=>x.Date).Except(dateList2.Select(y=>y.Date));
```

Though this ignores the time completely, meaning that in your result the time will be missing, too...

On a second thought: You could of course implement a custom `IEqualityComparer` to preserve the time in the result:

```
public class DateComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime left, DateTime right)
    {
        return left.Date.Equals(right.Date);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.Date.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use that comparer:

```
var missingDates = dateList1.Except(dateList2, new DateComparer());
```

Comment: See my modified answer on how to preserve the time in the result if neccessary...

Answer (score 1):

This will ignore the time in the comparison but return the dates with times intact:

```
List<DateTime> missingDates = dateList1.Where(list1Item => !dateList2.Exists(list2Item => list2Item.Date == list1Item.Date)).ToList();
```

Comment: Replace `Exists` with `Any` and then this is a valid answer, too.

Comment: @Spontifixus: what's wrong with Exists here?  It does the same as Any.

Comment: You are right Carl - my mistake was that I tried with LINQPad on two arrays. `Exists(Predicate<T> match)` is not a LINQ-method, but rather a method of the `List<T>`-class, thus on my arrays that won't work. So your answer deserves an upvote, too ;)